# Django How to filter and sort queryset by related model

Tags: python, django

I have this model relationship:

```
class Account:
    < ... fields ... >


class Balance(models.Model):       
    name = models.CharField(...)
    count = models.FloatField(...)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='balance')
```

Let's say we have some number of accounts. I need to filter these accounts by `balance__name` and sort by `balance__count`. I need sorted accounts, not a list of balances.

How do I do that? I don't even have any suggestions to find out a solution using iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a queryset like:

```
Account.objects.filter(
    balance__name='my_balance_name'
).order_by('balance__count')
```

Note that here an account can occur *multiple* times if there are multiple `Balance`s that have the given name.

If you want to sort in *descending* order (so from larger `count`s to smaller `count`s), then you should add a minus (`-`):

```
Account.objects.filter(
    balance__name='my_balance_name'
).order_by('-balance__count')
```

Comment: Is `balance__count` dynamic? Trying this and getting "Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field"

Comment: @lorenzo: does your `balance` have a `count` field? You did wrap it in a string right?

Comment: actually no, thought it was a dynamic notation...thanks for the insta-reply. I'd like to do this with count being the account count in this example, is that possible?

Comment: @lorenzo: you can `.annotate(..)` with [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) first, and then thus order by.